# C# WCF can't catch by MessageInspector the ?wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, idispatchmessageinspector

I try to catch all message send to my WCF public service.

I use WCF service extension and actually all end point are under control.

But when I try to get the wsdl like this :

`http://localhost/MyProject.MyPublicService/Service/PublicService.svc?singlewsdl`

or

`http://localhost/MyProject.MyPublicService/Service/PublicService.svc?wsdl`

I don't trigger `AfterReceiveRequest`... and this annoying me a lot.

Does someone know how to enter into `AfterReceiveRequest` when triggering the `?wsdl`?

I created a class inherited from `IServiceBehavior` and Attribute
Decorate the public service with the attribute.

Loop across all the `channelDispatcher` and for all endpoint for adding a `MessageInspector`.

My own opinion is what endpoint don't catch the request of the `?wsd`l...

But I really don't know how to do that...

If somebody have a clue I really appreciate.

David

Comment: Please include sample code of what you have tried, if possible an isolated piece of code which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Getting the WSDL is a metadata request, not a request sent to a service operation. That's why you can't intercept it with a MessageInspector. What is the **actual** problem that you want to solve? I think your question as-is is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). If you want to customize the WSDL programmatically, for example, there's the [IWsdlExportExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface you can look into.